# How to get URL from GridView using javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceVideo" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="VideoUrl" HeaderText="VideoUrl" 
            SortExpression="VideoUrl" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" 
            SortExpression="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Video_Name" HeaderText="Video_Name" 
            SortExpression="Video_Name" /> 
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonPlay" runat="server" CommandName="Play"
            CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"VideoUrl") %>'
            Text="Play" OnClientClick="playVideo()"></asp:Button>
```

**JavaScript code for play URL:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function playAudio(URL){
        if (URL != "")
        {
            document.Player.filename = URL;
            document.getElementsByName("mediaPlayer").src=URL; 
            document.getElementsByName("mediaPlayer").play();
            document.Player.showcontrols = true;
            document.Player.height = 40;
            document.Player.play();    
        }
    }
</script>
```

Can anyone tell me how to get URL value from gridview? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your button calls `playVideo()`.  You posted the JavaScript for `playAudio()`. Which is correct?

Comment: Why are you using a server control for your button?  Do you want that button to cause a postback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonPlay" runat="server" CommandName="Play" 
     CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"VideoUrl") %>' 
     Text="Play" 
     OnClientClick='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"VideoUrl", "playVideo('{0}')") %>'>
</asp:Button>
```

Comment: Thankx for reply..i has written given button code, i got error that is the server tag is not well formed.

Comment: @Rembo, I edited the example so the server tag is now well formed, can you try again?

Comment: Hello friends i am using windows media player to play videos and above i written function name is playVideo(). my code is here.

Answer (score 1):

I would change your BoundField into a TemplateField

```
<asp:TemplateField SortExpression="VideoUrl" HeaderText="Video Url">
    <span class='videoUrl<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "RowIndex") %>'><%# Eval("VideoUrl") %></span>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then, to get the url from row three:

```
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("videoUrl3")[0];
var url = span.textContent ? span.textContent : span.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
OnClientClick='<%# EVAL("VideoUrl", "return playAudio({0})") %>'/>
```

use this in your button .Hope it helps.